# How can I make a single connection between Angular and Express.js, by using socket.io JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, socket.io

Hi everyone I'm pretty new using socket.io, and I trying to build a simple implementation using Angular as frontend and Express as backend, here is what I'm trying.

Backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   console.log('a user connected');
   socket.on('disconnect', () => {
     console.log('user disconnected');
   });
 });

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`>> Socket ready: 3000`);
});
```

Frontend:
[App.Module.ts]

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SocketIoConfig, SocketIoModule } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';    
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';

const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://localhost:3000', options: {} };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[web-socket.service.ts]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WebSocketService {

  constructor( private socket:Socket) {}  
}
```

[main.component.ts]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WebSocketService } from 'src/app/public/service/web-socket.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private socketService: WebSocketService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

I am not sending any information yet, I am just trying to establish a connection, this is just one of the ways I have already tried, but every time I got this on the server side.

[image: These connections / disconnections are done automatically when I start both servers]

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, so what was the issue again?

Comment: This image is for one client only, connecting and disconnecting for no reason. That is my problem, unless it is normal behavior that I am not aware of.

Comment: `Websocket` has specific heartbeat packets. You need to send "ping"s and respond to "pong"s. Once the timeout is reached, the browser would close the conn. Better use `express-ws` instead of `socket.io` which can handle these behind the scene.

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution by changing the version of socket.io.